# Can I grow and produce fruit from the 2 seeds from my naval oranges?

Tags: citrus

Can the large 2 seeds I found in my naval orange be planted and reproduce?  If not, what type in south Tx would I need to buy and would I need to buy 2 to pollinate?

Comment: What's your USDA hardiness zone?

Comment: A seed has two genetic inputs, although some plants will self pollinate. So likely it is not exactly the same as the fruit it came from. Normally grafted plants are use for fruit trees.

Answer (score 1):

Orange trees (apart from Navel oranges) are usually self fertile, so you won't need two, but it will be a long time before you get fruit, around 7-12 years. However, Navel oranges are classed as 'seedless', which means you may find one or two seeds in a fruit, but they are always grafted trees because the seeds from a Navel orange don't come true, they will be hybrids, which may or may not resemble the parent tree. Further info here  https://www.garden.eco/do-navel-oranges-have-seeds